# Ionic3, angular & firebase get from db

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

Working on chat app. Pushing messages to the db works fine, but get query does not seem to work.

ts file looks like this, send message works pushes to db, works fine.
get message is not working.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.encryptedMessages = this.getMessage();
}

getMessage(){
  return this.db.list('/messenger');
}

sendMessage(){
  this.db.list("/messenger").push({
  username: this.username,
  message: this.message
 }).then(()=>{
  //what happens once message is sent
 });
}
```

html looks like this. Using *ngFor and async pipe to display all the messages retrieved from the db. Nothing renders on the screen

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div id="message" *ngFor="let m of encryptedMessages | async">
    <div class="username">{{ m.username }}</div>
    <div class="message"> {{ m.message }} </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to subscribe to your list.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getMessage().snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe((actions) => {
       this.encryptedMessages = actions.map((action) => {
          const data = action.payload.val();
          data.key = action.key;
          return data;
       });
    });
}

getMessage(){
  return this.db.list('/messenger');
}
```

Comment: that gives me an "object is not a function". Isn't the asyn pipe in my html file supposed to take care of that?